# How do I get the last 2 digits of the year in pandas?

Tags: pandas, datetime

I am trying to get the last 2 digits of the year (i.e. '00' from '2000'). Here is what I have:

Set up simple df, make 'year' column:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'20000701':[1,1,1], '20010701':[2,2,2]},orient='index',columns=['c0','c1','c2'])
df['Datetime']=pd.to_datetime(df.index)
df['year']=df['Datetime'].dt.strftime('%Y')
print(df)


          c0  c1  c2   Datetime year
20000701   1   1   1 2000-07-01  2000
20010701   2   2   2 2001-07-01  2001
```

Then I try t convert year to a string and grab the last 2:

```
df['year2']=str(df['year'])[-2:]
df['year2']
```

But that gives me "ct", which I don't understand:

```
          c0  c1  c2   Datetime  year year2
20000701   1   1   1 2000-07-01  2000    ct
20010701   2   2   2 2001-07-01  2001    ct
```

Comment: try `df['year2']=df['year'].str[-2:]`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df['year2']=df.year.str[2:]
print(df)
```

Or:

```
df['year2']=df['Datetime'].dt.strftime('%y')
print(df)

          c0  c1  c2   Datetime  year year2
20000701   1   1   1 2000-07-01  2000    00
20010701   2   2   2 2001-07-01  2001    01
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears the simplest answer is to use the lowercase 'y' with strftime:

```
df['year']=df['Datetime'].dt.strftime('%y')
```

Then there is no need for the .str[2:]

Although, based on anky_91's answer, I am confused why this works:

```
df['year']=df.year.str[2:]
```

But this does not:

```
df['month']=df['Datetime'].dt.strftime('%m')
df['month']=df.month.str
```

Apparently you need:

```
df['month']=df.month.str[:]
```

or just:

```
df['month']=df.month
```